# Back again to use Rails 2.3.5 from Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Recently, I had seen information about Rails 3.0 beta and I had wanted to trial it. So I used gem update and installed this version. But now, I need to go back to Rails 2.3.5.

How could I do it?

I was thinking about this two solutions:

1. Uninstalling Rails 3. I read that somebody removed Rails 3 by using gem uninstall but he came across some problems then. Did anyone try to remove it in this way?
2. Using different versions Rails at the same time. Is it possible at all? It will resolve all my problems but I could find nothing about this issue in google.

Hope somebody could help me :)

Greetings,
dreame4

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using Rails 2 and 3 side-by-side: http://cardarella.blogspot.com/2010/01/rails-2-rails-3-side-by-side.html

Comment: Ah, it's simpler than I thought. 

Thanks a lot! :)

Answer (score 8):

You can also use the rvm gem http://rvm.beginrescueend.com

Each install of ruby under rvm has it's own set of gems.

I installed beta 3 of rails on 1.8.7 but use 1.8.6 for my day to day rails 2.3.5 development and can switch easily between the two. I believe you can also have sets of gems for the same ruby version with rvm too.

Comment: Quite useful tool! Thanks for sharing :)

Answer (score 0):

"gem uninstall rails" then, you select wich version you want to delete. I didnt had any trouble.