# Can I run Rails 2 and Rails 3 side by side on the same development machine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I install Ruby on Rails 2.x and Ruby on Rails 3 side by side](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3475674/can-i-install-ruby-on-rails-2-x-and-ruby-on-rails-3-side-by-side)

I'm using Rails 3 to develop my applications. I've realized that there's a gem I need but it doesn't work on Rails 3 but does work on Rails 2 ([sms_fu](https://github.com/brendanlim/sms-fu)).

Can I run and develop Rails 2 and Rails 3 applications side by side or do I need to downgrade to Rails 2?

Am I going lose out on great Rails 3 features and better functionality by downgrading to Rails 2 if that's the only way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2232593/back-again-to-use-rails-2-3-5-from-rails-3  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=rails+rvm   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3218161/multiple-rails-version-in-the-same-machine

Answer (score 0):

The best engineering approach is to revrite sms_fu to play with rails 3, but quite good approach is to built one rails 2 app that sends sms and add api secured by single access token for instance, and send sms from rails 3 using this api.

Comment: nice approach, but one drawback, it assumes Im as good in rails as you are.

Comment: Second solution is very easy. You only need one action in controller that takes message and phone number from parameter and send it. And all you need is to invoke this action.